# How do run scala bytecode on the jvm?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

How do I run the compiled scala code on jvm?

When I try the following command:

`java -cp scala-library.jar -cp bin com.mcmc5.Main`

I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

In the scala code, I have an object called Main and it has the main function defined in there. It works if I do 

`scala -cp bin com.mcmc5.Main`
, it works fine.

Is there something that I am missing?

Thank you,
thejinx0r

**Edit1:**
Here's my code:
The reason why I want it to run on the JVM is because the server where I want to actually execute the bytecode does not have scala installed. This is what my main has essentially (it has some values and variables defined before it, but essentially: 

`package com.mcmc5
import java.text.{DateFormat, NumberFormat, DecimalFormat, SimpleDateFormat}
import java.util.{Date}
 object Main {  def main( args: Array[String]) = {
        println(numberOfOutputStructures)
        var structureSolver = new MC(20);
        structureSolver.start()
    }
}`

But I still tried using 
 `java -cp scala-library.jar:bin com.mcmc5.Main` and I still got the same error.

**Edit 2**
Problem solved.

So I actually don't believe this, but this works for me.

So I had found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135731/)
 ( if you can call it that ) and said that java usually does not like the whole  `object Main extends Application`  
But, that actually solved my problem. By using `extends Application` instead of defining a function called main solved my problem. I guess it depends on what version of scala you are using. I'm currently on scala 2.9, rc2 perhaps? or rc1?

Comment: would be nice to see your code to help you

Comment: As Ernest mentioned: Only the last -cp option will be used. Don't specify two!

Comment: With a command line `scala -cp bin com.mcmc5.Main`, you are already running your Scala code on the JVM. Why do you want to explicitly do it using the `java` command?

Comment: So I'm a little bit new to stack overflow and I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but if I edit my post, the original one, are people notified if they have answered the thread in the past?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Windows,

```
java -cp scala-library.jar;bin com.mcmc5.Main
```

or elsewhere

```
java -cp scala-library.jar:bin com.mcmc5.Main
```

Just a single combined "-cp" option. This is definitely the correct way, given that com.mcmc5.Main was compiled with `scalac`.